# Opening a Postgres Connection in Xamarin returns Error While Connecting

Tags: postgresql, xamarin.forms

I am trying to connect my Android Application to Postgres but seems not to work.

The Exception Message is: `Exception while Connecting`

This is my Code Behind,

```
 private void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DBInterface<DBLogicInput, DBLogicResult> dbLoginLogic = new DBLoginLogic();
            DBLogicInput userInput = new DBLogicInput();
            DBLogicResult DBResult = new DBLogicResult();
            LoginModel useCredentials = new LoginModel()
            {
                userName = txtUsername.Text,
                passWord = txtPassword.Text
            };

            userInput[typeof(LoginModel).FullName] = useCredentials;

            try
            {
                DBResult = dbLoginLogic.DoProcess(userInput);
                bool userExisting = DBResult.ResultCode != DBLogicResult.RESULT_CODE_ERR_DATA_NOT_EXIST;
                if (userExisting)
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new IndexPage());
                }
                else
                {

                    _ = DisplayAlert("Login Error", "User does not exist", "Ok");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is the Class I created to connect the DB.

```
  public abstract class DBLogic : DBInterface<DBLogicInput, DBLogicResult>
    {
        public string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=proyektoNijuan";
        public DBLogicResult DoProcess(DBLogicInput inOut)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            DBLogicResult result = default(DBLogicResult);
            NpgsqlConnection connection = null;
            NpgsqlTransaction transaction = null;
            try {
                connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
                if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                result = Process(connection, inOut);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                transaction.Rollback();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected abstract DBLogicResult Process(NpgsqlConnection conn, DBLogicInput InOuT);
    }
```

The error exists after the debugger hits the code `connection.Open();`.

Should I add a web services to connect the postgres to my android app built in xamarin forms?

I am only a beginner in Xamarin Forms. I am just trying to create a self application. And need a little help for me to learn a new platform in programming.

Thank you and Regards,

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I am doing it wrong.

Maybe the Right way to Connect the PostgreSQL is to have a WEB API.

Calling that web API to the Xamarin forms.

I really don't know if it is correct, but I will give it a try.

I will update the correct answer after I finish the development of that WEB API so that other beginners will found this answer helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, pkease do not forget to accept your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Currently, The WEB API is currently in development progress. Once it is done. I will post it here.